# In django allauth, how do I get the username from an OpenId login / Google?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I did see a couple similar questions, but they didn't quite seem to answer the problem I'm having.

So far, I've only been doing the `manage.py runserver`, running locally.

At first I tried just putting this in my settings.py:

```
import allauth
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

then tried extending it to:

```
import allauth
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
```

but when I try logging in with my google account(That is, under openId-googlem not the straight google), I can see that it gets my email, but it doesn't use my email.  In the callback function, I tried sticking in a bunch of print statements and it looked like it pulls this from the return url when I print the `user.__dict__` :

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x101604dd0>,
 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 3, 4, 35, 41, 949526, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'email': u'CORRECT_USERNAME@gmail.com',
 'first_name': '',
 'id': None,
 'is_active': True,
 'is_staff': False,
 'is_superuser': False,
 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 3, 4, 35, 41, 949506, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'last_name': '',
 'password': '',
 'username': ''}
```

That is, it populates the email field, but not the `username` field.  I thought that by default, allauth would have populated the `username` with `CORRECT_USERNAME`, but instead it looks empty.
Then when I print out the account, I don't see anything in the `user_id` field.

When i bounce to the profile page, it lists the `username` as "user," which looks like the absolute fallback/default.  That is, this:

```
{% user_display user %}
<p>Another try... <br />
{{user.username}}
<p>---------------------------</p>
{{ user.account_provider }}
<p>---------------------------</p>
{{ user.get_provider }}
<p>---------------------------</p>
```

gives me this:

```
 user

Another try...
user

---------------------------

---------------------------

---------------------------
```

I don't see any errors in the runserver console.

Is there something else I need to add to settings.py?
Is there some callback function I need to write to extract the username out of the email field?

I'm using python 2.6.1(Snow Leopard) if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of django-allauth are you using? Also, it seems that since you asked the question in Dec 12, there has been at least 12 versions of django-allauth released, the issue you are describing might have been resolved...

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the OpenID code of django-allauth, you can see that it does not extract the username but only the email, first_name, last_name and name:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/openid/provider.py#L65

As for the ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED setting you can see in the docs that it is used in the sign up form:

[ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED (=True)
The user is required to enter a username when signing up. Note that the user will be asked to do so even if ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD is set to email. Set to False when you do not wish to prompt the user to enter a username.](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html)

I hope that this helps you with your doubts.